# How to align header to top of the page?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm new here and I was wondering: how do I align my header to the top of the page? Right now there is too much white space between the header and top of the page. Is there a way to 'valign' it to the top somehow? Any help is appreciated. Thank you. Attached is my html code as well as CSS.

[image]

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Minion Pro, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h3 {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}

p,
ul {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 850px;
}

.container2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #dce4ea;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 850px;
}

.container3 {
  background-color: #375e97;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 850px;
  top: 0;
}

.container4 {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 850px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.subhead {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Minion Pro, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.title {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.cell {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.refund {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}

.button {
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  /**doubtful in emails**/
  background: #375e97;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  /**doubtful in emails**/
  background: #555;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Multifamily Texas – Early Bird Registration</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://interfaceconferencegroup.com/mftx18/images/MFTX.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container3">
    <h2>ACT NOW and SAVE $80!</h2>
    <p class="subhead">Early Bird Registration is $279 through August 17th</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container4">
    <table align="center" width="600" border="1" bordercolor="#375e97" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#375e97" align="center" colspan="2">
          <p class="title">Early Bird Registration Pricing</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%">
          <p class="cell">Single Attendee</p>
        </td>
        <td width="50%">
          <p class="cell">$279</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" bgcolor="#d3daee">
          <p class="cell">Two Attendees</p>
        </td>
        <td width="50%" bgcolor="#d3daee">
          <p class="cell">$568</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%">
          <p class="cell">Three Attendees</p>
        </td>
        <td width="50%">
          <p class="cell">$857</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" bgcolor="#d3daee">
          <p class="cell">Four Attendees</p>
        </td>
        <td width="50%" bgcolor="#d3daee">
          <p class="cell">$1146</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%">
          <p class="cell">Five Attendees</p>
        </td>
        <td width="50%">
          <p class="cell">$1435</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" bgcolor="#d3daee">
          <p class="cell">Six Attendees</p>
        </td>
        <td width="50%" bgcolor="#d3daee">
          <p class="cell">$1724</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Refund Policy</h3>
    <p class="refund"><b>InterFace Conference Group/France Media, Inc. Cancellation Policy:</b> If you cancel your attendance 30 days or more before the conference, you will be issued a full refund. Within 30 days, you will be given a credit for the amount you paid. This
      credit must be used within one year of the conference date to apply to another InterFace conference, for an equal or lesser amount.</p>
    <p class="refund" align="center">InterFace Conference Group/France Media, Inc. <a href="https://custom.cvent.com/7C0825B3546540A3BA33AF202D8A465F/files/7e42d5bc6e55405e8c8bd7f280de4d3c.doc" target="_blank">Attendance &amp; Substitution Policy</a> and <a href="https://custom.cvent.com/7C0825B3546540A3BA33AF202D8A465F/files/4c106328c8e140e4b66ba30f4659af92.docx"
        target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a></p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure where the white space is. You could put a circle around it in your screenshot (I am not a web developper).

Comment: "Between header and top of page" seems to mean "above the ACT NOW box (container3)".  However, when I run the snippet, that banner is at the very top of the result display (but possibly it can't find the CSS).  Or did you mean between the ACT NOW box and the pricing table (between container3 and container4)?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `<h2>`'s `margin-top` not being removed. Update this rule:

```css
h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Minion Pro, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic; 
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;   /* This one */
}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Here is a better picture. I thought it could be something in the container tag? So, I should remove 'margin-top: 0' in h2?  https://imgur.com/a/V7NSlgR

Comment: I tried to add 'margin-top: 0;' to h2, but the issue remains.

Comment: @easyhateoven Try hard resetting? It works for me... For some reason, your CSS seems to be cached on the page... `:(`